# Python 3.3 and TKinter, error message and crash

Tags: tkinter, python-3.3

As a hobby I like to dabble in this Python stuff. I am trying to make a simple program that will help my beloved wife track and identify food sensitivities. I have a working version of this already in place, but out of boredom I tried to improve it by adding a little ticker widget to the home screen. Upon doing so, I developed an error that I cannot figure out. I'm not even sure what its trying to tell me honestly. But it occurs whenever I click the "Next" button from the main menu.

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os, shelve


class Food:

    def __init__(self, name, score):
        self.name = name
        self.score = score


class Main:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master_frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.master_frame.pack()
        self.home_frame()

    def home_frame(self):
        for child in self.master_frame.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()    
        self.ticker = ' ' * 29
        self.start = 0
        self.end = 29
        for i in catalog.values():
            self.ticker = self.ticker + str(i.name) + ': ' + str(i.score) + '%' + ' ' * 10
        print(self.ticker)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):

        self.ticker_frame = Frame(self.master_frame, bd = 5, bg = 'black')
        self.ticker_label = Label(self.ticker_frame, text = '<empty>', fg = 'white', bg = 'black')
        self.ticker_label.grid(row = 0, columnspan = 3, sticky = E + W)
        self.ticker_frame.pack(expand = 1, fill = 'x', anchor = 'center')

        self.button_frame = Frame(self.master_frame, bd = 5, bg = 'black')
        Button(self.button_frame, text = 'Next', width = 10, command = self.next_win).grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        Button(self.button_frame, text = 'N/A', width = 10, command = self.master.destroy).grid(row = 0, column = 1)
        Button(self.button_frame, text = 'Exit', width = 10, command = self.master.destroy).grid(row = 0, column = 2)
        self.button_frame.pack()

        self.run_ticker()

    def run_ticker(self):
        ticker_text = self.ticker[self.start:self.end]
        self.ticker_label.config(text = ticker_text, font = ('courier', 10, 'bold'))
        self.start += 1
        self.end += 1
        if self.start == len(self.ticker):
            self.start = 0
            self.end = 29
        self.master.after(250, self.run_ticker)

    def next_win(self):
        for child in self.master_frame.winfo_children():
            child.destroy()
        self.next_frame = Frame(self.master_frame)
        new_label = Label(self.next_frame, text = 'Blah...').grid()
        Button(self.next_frame, text = 'Main', command = self.home_frame).grid()
        self.next_frame.pack()




x = Food('Grapes', 50)
y = Food('Cheese', 75)
z = Food('Eggs', 35)

catalog = {}

catalog[x.name] = x
catalog[y.name] = y
catalog[z.name] = z



root = Tk()
Main(root)

root.mainloop()
```

The error message I am getting, same for either button:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1442, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 501, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Gregory\Desktop\Test2 Working except ticker.pyw", line 111, in run_ticker
    self.ticker_label.config(text = ticker_text, font = ('courier', 10, 'bold'))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1230, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1221, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".52922632.52924032"
```

Mr. Oakley put it very eloquently when he responded to a previous question of mine, "unless you know what is going on under the hood..." and I obviously do not, which is why I have no clue what the shell is trying to tell me.

Also, a less important question:
I'm trying to keep the program's main menu in the upper right corner of the screen. My attempts have failed. It initializes away from the upper right corner, then upon opening a new window it moves properly, and then finally upon returning to the main menu, it falls into the proper position. Obviously I am missing something here too.

Thanks as always!

Comment: This is just way too much code. I don't think all of these are relevant. Please narrow it down to make it [MCVE].

Comment: Also, most of the times that error occurs because there is no parent window for that command to execute. You either destroyed it or ran that command before it's created.

Comment: I apologize, I posted the whole thing because I didn't know where to begin to find the problem. I will try to recreate the issue with a smaller sample and edit in a bit. I'll also look at the parent issue you mentioned. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a destroy

```
def next_win(self):
    for child in self.master_frame.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
```

which contains ticker_frame and all of it's widgets, so the after statement in  run_ticker() is still calling the function after the frame has been destroyed.    Use some variable like self.is_tinker_frame = True when the frame is created, and set it to False when the frame is destroyed plus:

```
if self.is_tkinter_frame:
    self.master.after(250, self.run_ticker)
```

Additionally, wait longer than 250 after the variable is set to False, to destroy the frame, to allow any calls to finish.

Comment: So to make sure I understand you correctly, I have destroyed the widget but without stopping the ticker. The ticker is trying to continue, causing the error. I did not think of that. Brilliant and thank you! I'll try to add the boolean like you suggested. Any idea as to the .geometry window placement problem I am having?

Comment: Fix this problem and start a new thread for the geometry problem with simple code that illustrates it.

Comment: Problem fixed with the solution you provided. Thanks!